# Redirect with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Hi My problem is I want to make a redirect and "hide" the actual address so I want to enable and show this address:

```
/saopaulo
```

The actual address the response has is

```
/li?lat=-23.33&lon=-46.38
```

but I don't want the user the view that address, only the view and display in the address bar /saopaulo and similar for other and more cities. How can I do this with app engine?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't actually require redirections.

In your code, when you get a request for /saopaulo simply call the code which you would call if you got the request for /li?lat=-23.33&lon=-46.38. You could store these city name -> lat&lon mappings in your code as a dictionary, or make a model for them.

Comment: Thank you Bemmu. I'll follow this advice doing a self.redirect but then the address bar address changes. I suppose I just do a call and not a redirect.

Comment: @Web Or better, make your handler capable of doing the name resolution itself. There's no need to have another handler that you only ever call via the named URLs.

Comment: @Nick thanks for the comment. I'm still thinking about how to do it since I'm no app engine guru yet.